# Authenticate Email VIA SPF

Tags: php, gmail, schema, tls1.2, spf

Okay, I cant figure this out. I am using PHPMailer to send an email from my domain - example.com to myself. I am sending the email to myself.(testing the google schema markup), but the emails are not authenticated.
Here is the code I use to send the email to myself.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';      
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Microdata Test';
$html = '
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context":       "http://schema.org",
            "@type":          "EmailMessage",
            "description":    "Check this out",
            "potentialAction": {
                "@type": "ViewAction",
                "target":   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH8KwfdkSqU"
                }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
        This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
';

$mail->msgHTML($html);
$mail->send();
```

Here is my spf record:

> v=spf1 a mx include:mailgun.org include:mydomain.com ~all

Comment: SPF is only domain anti-spoofing mechanism. Have you tried adding DKIM  record to your DNS?

Comment: My goal is to use SPF only. My understanding was it was enough.

Comment: You can't stop spoofing with just SPF. With hardfail in spf most you can do is send it to spam. If you want to stop it from spamming then only way is to use all SPF, DKIM and specially DMARC with policy `reject`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending the email with Google's smtp, you have to include it in your SPF:

```
include:_spf.google.com
```

Comment: This is how my SPF records looks like now: v=spf1 a mx include:mailgun.org include:mydomain.com include:_spf.google.com ~all Just tried to send another email and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending from your host to google over SMTP. This means that Google will see if you host is in your SPF record and act accordingly

So, you have to  include your public ip in the SPF record and pray that this is enough.

Also, your username is `myemail` not `myemail@gmail.com`. And password should be the real password, of course.

If nothing works, consult PHPMailer logs, there should be more hints.

Comment: I added the domain public address, now my record looks like v=spf1 a mx include:xx.xx.xx.xx include:mailgun.org include:domain.com include:_spf.google.com ~all . I tried to send another email and it is still not authenticated.

Comment: To reference an IP address replace include:xx.xx.xx.xx with ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx